# Extract .tgz with a cronjob

Tags: php, ftp, cron

I have .tgz file posted to my ftp server at intervals, the .tgz contain .xml files.

I want to extract the .xml and parse them into database.

This is what I have done so far.  In shell script, I have this command

```
#!/bin/sh

tar -zxvf /public_html/2230114.tgz -C /public_html/NewFolder

//this file should then be deleted once it is uncompressed
```

Then I have a cron job which runs after every 2 minutes, to uncompress the .tgz files uploaded via FTP.

```
/bin/sh /public_html/uncompress.sh
```

The result is an empty folder.

I have tried the code on the terminal and it is absolutely fine
what am I not doing right?

Comment: Do you know if the `uncompress.sh` even runs? If you know that it runs, redirect an output of `tar` to a file and check for any errors: `tar ... >/tmp/uncompress.out 2>&1`

Comment: In your Terminal, run `which tar` and then use the full path to `tar` in your script.